# Escaping characters in variables inside sed expression

Tags: bash, sed

So im having an issue where this portion of my script is not working. I'm not sure exactly whats going on, but I get the feeling its because I have not escaped certain characters inside the variables. I tried the following with no luck:

```
crontab -l | sed "s%$CTMP%\*\/$FREQ \* \* \* \* cd $DIR && \.\/$SCRIPT%" | crontab -
```

Here is whats in each of the variables:

The CTMP variable is just a line from the crontab file

```
CTMP='*/5 * * * * cd /home/admin/whatever && ./test.sh'
```

The `FREQ` variable is the time in minutes setting of the cron file

```
FREQ=5
```

The DIR variable is the current working directory

```
DIR='/home/admin/whatever'
```

And the SCRIPT variable is just the script file name

```
SCRIPT='test.sh'
```

I feel like the issue is the sed statement is not updating the crontab file because it's not escaping the characters it needs to inside these variables above.

Is that correct or is something else wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

```
CTMPESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.]/\\&/g' <<<"$CTMP")
DIRESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.]/\\&/g' <<<"$DIR")
SCRIPTESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.]/\\&/g' <<<"$SCRIPT")
crontab -l | sed "s%$CTMPESC%\*/$FREQ \* \* \* \* cd $DIRESC && \./$SCRIPTESC%" | crontab -
```

*** UPDATE ***

Here is the crontab output

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 */7 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh*/7 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh ./anm.sh
```

and I also echoed the three escaped variables just to troubleshoot and here they are:

```
\*/7 \* \* \* \* cd /home/administrator/anm-1\.5\.0 && \./anm\.sh
/home/administrator/anm-1\.5\.0
anm\.sh
```

The three escaped variables actually look good.

*** UPDATE ***

Cron file before the replace:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh
```

Cron file after the replace:

```
*/7 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 */10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh*/10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh ./anm.sh
```

See all the extra junk that gets thrown in there somehow?

Comment: Try setting `noblog`.  `set -f` before setting `CTMP`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape a string for sed search pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the problem is likely that `$CTMP` contains asterisks, which are interpreted by `sed` as quantifiers. `.` is also a special character. Try escaping them:

```
CTMP_ESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.]/\\&/g' <<<"$CTMP")
```

and then use `CTMP_ESC` instead of `CTMP`.

Also, you don't need to escape `/` in your `sed` command, because you are not using it as the `s///` separator.

**Edit:** you also need to escape `&` in the replacement, because `sed` interprets `&` as "the matched string". So your script should read:

```
CTMPESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&]/\\&/g' <<<"$CTMP")
DIRESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&]/\\&/g' <<<"$DIR")
SCRIPTESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&]/\\&/g' <<<"$SCRIPT")
crontab -l | sed "s%$CTMPESC%\*/$FREQ \* \* \* \* cd $DIRESC \&\& \./$SCRIPTESC%" | crontab -
```

Comment: That almost worked! It finally updated, but it added some duplicate stuff to the cron file as well, but at least this means we're very close. See my code above.

Comment: @user2272450 What do you mean by duplicate stuff? It's hard to tell without seeing the crontab. Did the substitution happen more than once? What were the matching lines?

Comment: @user2272450 And what was the initial content of the crontab?

Comment: Different test some number may be different. Before Replace: */10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh After replace: */7 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 */10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh*/10 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh ./anm.sh

The only thing that should change in this case is the 10 should change to a 7

Comment: @user2272450 I get it now! Will update the answer in a moment

Comment: Doing a bit more testing but I think you got it! Thank you very much for actively helping me with this!!!